# Get value from different class inside an event

Tags: java, swing, instance, instance-variables

I have two classes:

```
public jComboBox() {
... // this is a autocomplete jComboBox btw
...
   combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {

            if(ie.getStateChange() == 1) {
                String selectedItem = (String)getSelectedItem();
                randomMethod(selectedItem);

         }
        }
    });
}

 private void randomMethod(String selectedItem){
    someClass sc = new someClass();
    String randomString = selectedItem;
    sc.getRandomString(randomString);

}
```

and

```
public someClass() {
...
...
  }
public void getRandomString(String randomString){
   defaultTableModel.setRowCount(0);
.. do-something ..
 }
```

Is this method fine? If not, I need some alternative on this one, because i'm having problems for example, using defaultTableModel.setRowCount(0) because the table wont empty, not unless I put the setRowCount(0) on other methods inside someClass class.

Comment: The second class is definitely not fine. How are you putting this function outside the class definition and inside the same file?

Comment: It's inside the class.. 'public someClass()' is a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic java access specifier stuff..... how are you calling this private method `getRandomString` from `randomMethod()`? the visibility of private method of a class is only the class, not anywhere else. Therefore, your following code:

```
 private void randomMethod(String selectedItem){
    someClass sc = new someClass();
    String randomString = selectedItem;
    fs.getRandomString(randomString); // This will not work

}
```

is not going to work because of the access specifier `private`. If you can allow the access rights to be specific to the package you have, you can change it to:

```
protected void getRandromString(String randromString) {...}
```

Just to demonstrate what I mean:

```
package com.stackoverflow.solutionmaker;

public class Aclass {

    public Aclass(){
        somePrivMethod();
    }

    public void aMethod(){
        System.out.println("Can see me from anywehre bcoz I am public");
    }

    private void somePrivMethod(){
        System.out.println("Cannot find me from anywhere because I am private t Aclass");
    }

}
```

Now the runner class:

```
package com.stackoverflow.solutionmaker;

public class StackOverflowSolutionsRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Aclass aClass = new Aclass(); // It will display"Cannot find me from anywhere because I am private t Aclass"

        aClass.aMethod(); // It will display "Can see me from anywehre bcoz I am public

        aClass.somePrivMethod(); // Will throw a compile-time error


    }
}
```

A good exercise for you now to compile these two from command line and see what error message you get. Alternatively, using Eclipse smart IDE or Jcreator, you can see that your private access specifier is causing red messages to appear.

Comment: @meatno        can you not use shorthands and be clear about what you mean?

Comment: I'm using eclipse right now.. And I really don't get any error messages :| I dunno why is that

Comment: nvm it's on public im really really srry :|